# My data in IDESplash

Tags: delphi

Win 8.1 Ent (+all update), Rad Xe 6.1 Arch.

In principle, the problem (MY and this) described in circulation

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=90619

Last post - (Posted: Oct 3, 2013 11:39 AM)

Again.

There is a small component consisting of two packets - RT + DT. 
The package RT is a small function in the package DT - (registration component and the procedure icon display on IDE splash) + component on boot IDE.

I have tried different options:

1) [Delphi OTA interface - AddPluginBitmap function does not display the caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580222/delphi-ota-interface-addpluginbitmap-function-does-not-display-the-caption)

2) just to the "Registered" proc. in component in DT added

```
SplashScreenServices.AddPluginBitmap('MyComp', LoadBitmap(HInstance, 'MyBitMap'));
```

3) components TMS module is TMSSplash (its done the same way)

```
unit TMSSplash; interface

uses ToolsApi, Windows, Classes, Graphics;

{$R TMSSPLASH.RES}

implementation

uses TMSPackVersion;

procedure AddSplash;
var bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  {$IFDEF ConditionalExpressions}
  {$if CompilerVersion >= 18}
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmp.LoadFromResourceName(HInstance, 'TMSSPLASH');
    SplashScreenServices.AddPluginBitmap(GetProductName + ' for ' + GetCompilerVersion + ' ' + GetProductVersion,bmp.Handle,false,'Registered','');
  finally
    bmp.Free;
  end;
  {$ifend}
  {$ENDIF}
end;

begin
  AddSplash; // ShowMessage ('Added!')
end.
```

4) Was added, and "procedure Register" and "begin .. end" (and tried to make a separate module, as in the TMS), and in the "Initialization .. end".

5) I tried to add "ShowMessage ('Added!')" With AddSplash;

6) Tried image separately (in my.rc file)

MyBitMap BITMAP "1.bmp"

p.s.

1. I Bitmap added a "menu \ project \ resourses and images" (and out *.rc\res tested and add as {$R ..} to unit)
2. All path for bpl, dcu - added in tools \ options \ env .. \ library \ path
3. IDE run as Admin all the time

PROBLEM:

1. Installations Comp everything is OK (and if the procedure added "ShowMessage" - and I see the message). On click "Install" and first reboot IDE.
2. After rebooting your IDE component see the palette (and it works).
3. The icon component appears immediately after the restart IDE
4. After the second and subsequent reboots IDE - icon on the Splash not watch :( This package is listed, and is active on the panel see the component (and it works).

What are the solutions? 
Thank you.

p.s. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: +1 to negate the down vote as I think it does show some research effort.

Comment: @Shambhala: That's not how this should work. To quote from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253386/30568: _You should vote based on the **merits of the question or answer** that you're voting on. If you vote to "cancel out" other people's opinions, you make a mockery of the whole voting process._

Comment: the answers here: http://rghost.ru/57280491 or https://www.sendspace.com/file/0s2i2d (mirrors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code from the JEDI VCL (JVCL) uses this at the end of `JvCoreReg.pas`, and it works properly every time the IDE loads.

```
procedure RegisterSplashScreen;
var
  ProductImage: HBITMAP;
begin
  Assert(Assigned(SplashScreenServices), RsENoSplashServices);
  ProductImage := LoadBitmap(FindResourceHInstance(HInstance), 'JVCLSPLASH');
  SplashScreenServices.AddPluginBitmap(RsAboutDialogTitle, ProductImage,
    False, RsAboutLicenceStatus);
end;

initialization
  RegisterSplashScreen;
  RegisterAboutBox;       // registers info to display in IDE's about box

finalization
  UnRegisterAboutBox;

end.
```

The `RsENoSplashServices`, `RsAboutDialogTitle`, and `RsAboutLicenceStatus` values are resource strings declared in `JvDsgnConsts.pas`, partially quoted below for completeness:

```
resourcestring
  RsENoSplashServices = 'Unable to get Borland Splash Services';
  RsAboutDialogTitle = 'JEDI Visual Component Library';
  RsAboutLicenceStatus = 'MPL 1.1';
```

Note the location of the `RegisterSplashScreen` call in the `initialization` section, so that it executes every time the design-time package is loaded.

Comment: `RsENoSplashServices` is an error message that's used if the assertion fails. `Rs` is a common prefix used for `Resource string`, and JEDI uses a file that contains those constants. Surely you know how `Assert` works and could have figured that out yourself. :-) The same applies to `RsAboutDialogTitlle` and `RsAboutLicenceStatus` in the call to `AddPlugInBitmap` - they're resource strings.

Comment: "sorr, but none"? What does *that* mean?

Comment: I explained the `RegisterAboutBox` with a comment; it's the registration code for the JEDI JVCL info in the IDE's About Box, just like the comment says. Your question is about the splash screen, so just **ignore** the part related to the About Box.